# Java8: Map list of objects by key

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
Map<A, List<B>> xFunction() {    
    Map<A, List<B>> mapList = new HashMap<>();
    List<A> aList = x.getAList();
    for (A a : aList) {
        List<B> bList = getBList(a.getId());
        mapList.put(a, bList);
    }
    return mapList;
}
```

How to convert this in java 8 with collect and grouping by or mapping?

I try with something like:

```
x.getAList
.stream()
.map(a -> getBList(a.getId)) //return a list of B
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy (...) )
```

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Eran was first but to reproduce behavior you should use `toMap` collector with `mergeFunction` for duplicates by `a.getId()` because by default Java will throw `IllegalStateException` for entries with the same key:

```
x.getAList()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), a -> getBList(a.getId())), (u, u2) -> u2);
```

Answer (score 6):

You need `Collectors.toMap`:

```
Map<A, List<B>> map =
    x.getAList()
     .stream()
     .collect(Collectors.toMap (Function.identity(), a -> getBList(a.getId())));
```

Comment: You were 30s faster than me.